# How to Retrieve Facebook Post details?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I can successfully query for a post with this code, unfortunately, the only information it return is the created_time, message, and id.  How do I get the other information like title, desc, link and image?

```
FB.api(
    '/1494363804210145_10152988081617735', 
    function(response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
            $("#postTitle").val(response.caption); // doesn't works
            $("#postMessage").val(response.message); // works
            $("#postDesc").val(response.description); // doesn't works
            $("#postLink").val(response.link); // doesn't works
            $("#postImage").val(response.picture); // doesn't works
            writeFeedback("Post is loaded.");
        }else{
            writeFeedback("Error Reading Post: "+response.error.message);
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the fields you want to be returned from the Graph API specifically. This was introduced with v2.4.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

> **Declarative Fields**
>   To try to improve performance on mobile networks, Nodes and Edges in v2.4 requires that you explicitly request the field(s) you need for your GET requests. For example, GET /v2.4/me/feed no longer includes likes and comments by default, but GET /v2.4/me/feed?fields=comments,likes will return the data. For more details see the docs on how to request specific fields.